# How can I use the latest version of the gem "shoulda" in my project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my GEM file i have:

```
gem 'shoulda'
```

But I would like to use the latest version. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will use the latest version available as a gem. If a new version of shoulda was released since you wrote it in Gemfile, you will have to use `bundle update shoulda`, so it will get updated (according to the version specified in your Gemfile, which in your case means the latest available).

You can also set it so it use the git repository as source, and then you'll truly have the latest version. I suggest you read gembundler manual for more on this topic